# Passing variable to a PHP page with Spaces

Tags: javascript, php

I have a select element as shown below.I am passing the value of the selected option to a PHP page as a variable with javascript as shown below :

```
<script>
var area1=document.getElementById("area").value;
$("#list").load("selectcity.php?city1="+city1+"&area1="+area1);
<script>

<select id="areas" name="areas">
<option value="Queens Town">Queens Town</option>
<option value="QueensTown">QueensTown</option>
</select>
```

Now the thing is , In the PHP page I am able to echo $_GET['area1']; when QueensTown is selected but whenever I am trying to pass Queens Town ,its now working.Can anybody help.

Comment: is city1 populated? You might be getting a js error. what does console say?

Comment: Also close the `</script>` tag.

Comment: $("#list").load("selectcity.php?city1="+encodeURIComponent(city1)+"&area1="+encodeURIComponent(area1)); worked.thanks 2 all

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape the values properly, otherwise you would end up with a URL like this:

```
selectcity.php?city1=xyz&area1=Queens Town
```

Which is unlikely to work the way you want. Use this instead:

```
var data = {
    city1: city1,
    area1: $('#areas').val()
};

$('#list').load('selectcity.php?' + $.param(data));
```

See also: [`jQuery.param()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/)